# processing Postfix log with python

Tags: python, logging

I need to process all log messages from Postfix (`/var/log/mail/mail.log`), and print a summary/statistics (how many emails were sent/received and from/to which email addresses)

The situation is made more complicated by the fact, that Postfix has multi-line log entries (in contrast, `Apache` for example, has single line entries and the task would have been much easier).

A sample Postfix log might look something like this:

```
2013-12-03 14:40:45  postfix:  6F1AA10B: client=unknown[64.12.143.81]
2013-12-03 14:40:45  postfix:  6F1AA10B: message-id=<529DDF56.6050403@aol.com>
2013-12-03 14:40:45  postfix:  6F1AA10B: from=<martin.vegter@aol.com>, size=1571, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2013-12-03 14:40:45  postfix:  6F1AA10B: to=<martin@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.13
2013-12-03 14:40:45  postfix:  6F1AA10B: removed

2013-12-03 14:52:07  postfix:  9DD9610B: client=unknown[209.85.219.65]
2013-12-03 14:52:07  postfix:  9DD9610B: message-id=<CANE3EAQUsGwj6ZBAU-awymzsG=76XZnHih@mail.gmail.com>
2013-12-03 14:52:07  postfix:  9DD9610B: from=<martin.vegter@gmail.com>, size=2388, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2013-12-03 14:52:07  postfix:  9DD9610B: to=<martin@example.com>, orig_to=<martin@example.com>, relay=local
2013-12-03 14:52:07  postfix:  9DD9610B: removed
```

Every email message that was processed by Postfix has a unique message ID (in my example `6F1AA10B`).

What would be the best approach to process the logs in Python? What data structure would you recommend to use for storing the entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you store your items depends on how you are processing them further; in-memory aggregating is very different from storing individual items in rows in a SQL database, for example.

Parsing could be done by grouping records on a specific element in the line. Presumably an event for a given message ID can span multiple timestamps, but you *can* parse out lines into a dictionary, then use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group parsed lines.

I'll not go into the line parsing itself, but if we assume that a dictionary is produced to with a `msgid` key you can do:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

for msgid, messages in groupby(parsed_lines, key=itemgetter('msgid')):
    for message in messages:
        # Each `message` is a dictionary where the `msgid` is the same
```